# How to open a browser and keep it open between coded UI tests in Visual Studio 2017 using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, coded-ui-tests

I am trying to make some coded UI tests to help automate some of the manual testing at the company I work at. I am pretty new to the CUIT part of visual studio, but I feel like I am figuring it out. However I am having an issue with the testing thread being closed before the other tests run.

So I want to make this testing fully automated, as in, all the developer will need to do is to click "Run all" and they will all run automatically. The problem that I am having is that the very first test needs to launch Internet Explorer, go to a website, and log into the website. The rest of the tests are based off of being logged into the system. However, after the first test, the browser closes and gets killed along with the first test method.

Any advice on this would be great, I have searched online for some answers but a lot are for very old versions of visual studio, and the ones I have tried don't work.

Thank you.

Edit: So inside each class lets say "CodedUITest1.cs", I can use the same browser in each of the [Test Method]s that I have in that class (as someone suggested below). The issue I have is that if I want a different test class to test different functionality, "CodedUITest2.cs", the browser will close when the first class finishes its tests.

Comment: What have you tried and what happened? If you do not [edit] the question to explain what methods did not work for you then you are inviting people to describe the standard methods again. It may be that you have made a mistake in how you applied the methods you found. There have only been subtle changes in Coded UI between the versions of Visual Studio since 2010, plus a few enhancements, so the older well tried techniques should work. If you do not explain what you have tried then this question may be closed as too broad or as a debugging problem that does not contain a [mcve].

Comment: @AdrianHHH I added enough information in an edit that you should be able to understand what I am talking about. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, then This [code segment](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5cb4ed2f-f38e-4c4a-a703-cb45dbf98c82/coded-ui-test-browser-closes-after-each-test?forum=vsautotest) should work for you:

```
BrowserWindow window;

    [TestMethod]
    public void Method1()
    {
        window = BrowserWindow.Launch(new Uri("http://www.bing.com"));
        window.CloseOnPlaybackCleanup = false;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Method2()
    {
        window = BrowserWindow.Locate("Bing");
        window.CloseOnPlaybackCleanup = false;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Method3()
    {
        window = BrowserWindow.Locate("Bing");
    }
```

After reading the new info of this question, I have tested the code a bit. If you want to keep the browser open between CodeUITes1.cs and CodedUITest2.cs, then the following code segment may help you. It is adopted from the following link: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2012/11/08/coded-ui-test-why-does-application-close-after-each-test-in-visual-studio-2012/

File: CodedUITest1.cs

```
public class CodedUITest1
    {
        static BrowserWindow browserWindowInstance = null;
        public void LoadLocalHost()
        {
            if (browserWindowInstance == null)
            {
                browserWindowInstance = BrowserWindow.Launch(new System.Uri("YourWebSiteAddress"));

            browserWindowInstance.CloseOnPlaybackCleanup = false;
            browserWindowInstance.Maximized = !browserWindowInstance.Maximized;
        }
        else
        {
            browserWindowInstance.Maximized = !browserWindowInstance.Maximized;
        }
    }

[TestMethod]
    public void CodedUITestMethod1()
    {
        LoadLocalHost();
        // To generate code for this test, select "Generate Code for Coded UI Test" from the shortcut menu and select one of the menu items.
        this.UIMap.ClickNewsAndEvents();
    }
```

CodedUITest2.cs file:

```
 [TestMethod]
    public void CodedUITestMethod2()
    {
        CodedUITest1 obj1 = new CodedUITest1();
        obj1.LoadLocalHost();
        // To generate code for this test, select "Generate Code for Coded UI Test" from the shortcut menu and select one of the menu items.
        this.UIMap.ClickNewsPage();

    }
```

You can add more CodedUITest classes. Just create a new object like obj1 in the code sample of CodedUITest2 class, and use LoadLocalHost() method that resides in CodedUITest1.class from any subsequent classes. Hoping this will resolve your problem.

Comment: I added enough information in an edit that you should be able to understand what I am talking about. Sorry about the confusion

Comment: Hi Paul, just added more code sample that you can use.